# Unable to set focus on angular editor using document.getelementById(id)

Tags: angular

I am using dyanamic id for angular-editor. But I am unable to set the focus programatically.

I have tried the below code.

```
document.getElementById(id).focus();
```

But always occurs this error

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'focus')
```

Comment: I guess your HTML does not have the id.

Comment: It also depends where you're executing that code. Your editor might not have been loaded yet or some loading condition is keeping it from being rendered. Some more context would be ideal here.

Comment: You are probably trying to query too early, add to AfterViewInit hook.

Comment: Also, use ViewChild.

Comment: @AmolBhagat where you are trying to set this focus method call, in ngAfterViewInit() or any method click function..

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
setTimeout(() => { document.getElementById(id).focus(); }, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please place it in `AfterViewInit`

Please use the `@ ViewChild()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a `@ViewChild` to get access to the HTML element.

```
<mat-form-field class="form-mat-field ml-5">
            <mat-label class="filter-label">Name</mat-label>
            <input matInput formControlName"name" type="text" #myElement/>
</mat-form-field>
```

In the HTML mark the element you want to access in the ts Component with for ex. `#myElement` .

```
@ViewChild('myElement') firstItem: ElementRef;

....

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.firstItem.nativeElement.focus();
  }
```

In the component you can then access that marked element with the `@ViewChild`.